# Exclude partial weeks from results BQ SQL

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to find an easy way to exclude partial weeks from the results.

What I have so far:

```
WITH a AS (SELECT 
  FORMAT_DATE("%G-%V", created_date) as report_week 
, created_date  
, FORMAT_DATE('%A', created_date) AS day 
, emp_id 
, ROUND(SAFE_DIVIDE(SUM(working_time),3600),2) as hours 
    FROM `table1` a
          WHERE created_date >= current_date()-10
                GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5)


SELECT
  report_week
, emp_id
, hours
  FROM a
    WHERE day LIKE '%Monday%' 
      GROUP BY 1,2,3
        ORDER BY report_week ASC
```

Input:

**report_week**: conversion of employee's shift date into week

**created_date**: date of employee's shift

**day**: conversion of date of employee's shift into day of week (Monday, Tuesday..)

**emp_id**: the employee's ID

**hours**: Number of worked hours by the employee

if `current_date` is 19 April 2022 then `current_date()-10` is 9 April 2022.

Output:
The desired output is to return the number of hours worked for each employee during the full week 11 - 17 April only (it would exclude 9th, 10th, 18th and 19th of April from the results).

To obtain this, I tried to filter by having only week starting on a Monday with `WHERE day LIKE '%Monday%'` but in the example, it would also return the number of hours worked for each employee on 18th and 19th (since the 18th is a Monday). And if I combine this clause with AND (for example `WHERE day LIKE '%Monday%' AND day LIKE '%Sunday%'`, it does not work at all.

Additionally, I see here another potential problem. If a Monday is a day off (like during Easter), then no employees will have `hours` on that Monday and the rest of the week will then not be returned.

My question: Is there an easy way to get only full weeks (Monday-Sunday) regardless the date range chosen?

Thank you in advance.

Best,

Fabien

Comment: I don’t understand exactly what the input data and the expected output are. You can check in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) how to create a Complete and Verifiable example. You can update your question, and we can help you.

Comment: Hi @RaulSaucedo Thank you for your answer and sorry for my late one. I was away from my laptop due to holidays followed by COVID sickness. I have edited my post and I hope it makes it more understandable. Please let me know if it was still unclear and I'll try something else. Best

Comment: I alredy changed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `UNNEST` and create an array with a range of dates. Also, you need to use `DATE_TRUNC` to get the week and `LAST_DAY` to get the last day of the week. You can get the weeks that belong to each day in a range of dates.

You can see this example.

```
   with sample_data as (
    SELECT date FROM UNNEST(generate_timestamp_array('2022-04-09 00:00:00', '2022-04-19 00:00:00', INTERVAL 1 DAY)) as date
),
counting as(

select
    DATE_ADD(DATE (date), INTERVAL 1 DAY) date 
    , DATE_TRUNC(DATE(date), WEEK)+1 week_start
    , DATE_TRUNC(DATE(date), WEEK) +7 week_end
    from sample_data
)

select b.date from (
select week_start,count(*) as ndays 
from counting
group by week_start
having ndays=7

) a 
join counting b on a.week_start=b.week_start
where timestamp(b.date) between timestamp(b.week_start)  and timestamp(b.week_end)
```

[image]

I used the same range of dates like your example.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I have changed all the `WEEK` to `WEEK(MONDAY)` to get the `week_start` on Monday and tested the query. It seems that it returns also a partial week (2022-02-10, 2022-02-11, 2022-02-12, 2022-02-13) while it should only return full weeks regardless the date range.

Comment: @Fabien Did my answer help you?

Comment: It did not but thank you :)

Comment: @Fabien I updated my answer with a new query.

Comment: I still cannot manage to make it work properly but it is probably on my end. I'll vote for your answer as soon as I manage something. Thank you again for your answer and for your time :)